# How to find the offset of a relatively positioned element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to find the offsets (so called) of a html element if its parent has a relative positioning.

This jsFiddle explains my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/10hexdt1/

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// CASE 1
console.log(canvas.offsetTop,canvas.offsetLeft);

// CASE 2
content.style.position = 'relative';
console.log(canvas.offsetTop,canvas.offsetLeft);

console.log('how do i get "offsets" in second case?');
```

```css
#app {
  background:yellow;
  padding:20px;
}

#content {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}

#canvas {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Problem !</h1>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="canvas">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking for [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)?

Comment: @Siguza Yep that works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, the **[offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLelement/offsetParent)** of the canvas is the document.body, and all `offset*` properties are based on that.

When this is executed:

```
content.style.position = 'relative';
```

… `content` becomes the canvas's offsetParent.

If you want to keep the offsets relative to document.body, use **[getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)**:

```
console.log(canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top, canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// CASE 1
console.log(canvas.offsetTop,canvas.offsetLeft);

// CASE 2
content.style.position = 'relative';
console.log(canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top, canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

```css
#app {
  background:yellow;
  padding:20px;
}

#content {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}

#canvas {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Problem !</h1>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="canvas">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```